# Multiple video filters in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, multiplexing

I want to add a PNG watermark and then scale my video. I may add more filters. This is my FFmpeg command.

```
sweb@sweb-laptop:/tmp$ ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv -sn -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libvpx -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -b:v 384k -r 25 -vf "movie=/tmp/icon.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2 [out], scale=480:-1" video.webm
```

… but it gave me an error:

```
Simple filtergraph 'movie=/tmp/icon.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2 [out], scale=480:-1' does not have exactly one input and output.
Error opening filters!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[in][watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2 [out], scale=480:-1"
```

..has `[out]` in the wrong place, which renders the filtergraph meaningless. It should be:

```
[in][watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2, scale=480:-1[out]"
```

Personally I dislike the movie filter, for purely aesthetic reasons (I think it makes the command-line look less clear). I would do this using filter_complex instead:

```
ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv -i /tmp/icon.png \
-filter_complex '[0:v][1]overlay=W/2-w/2:H/2-h/2,scale=480:-1[outv]' \
-map [outv] -map 0:a -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -c:v libvpx -b:v 384k output.webm
```

Note that filter_complex is incompatible with `[in]`, since by its nature it takes multiple inputs.

I've removed `-ar 44100` and `-r 25`, since you probably don't need them - if your input source has a frame rate of 25fps and an audio rate of 44100, the output will inherit those settings by default. And if it doesn't, you probably won't gain anything by changing them.

---

To scale the video first, and then add a watermark, you could use something like this:

```
-vf 'movie=/tmp/icon.png[wm];[in]scale=480:-1[int];[int][wm]overlay=W/2-w/2:H/2-h/2[out]'
```

I'm not actually sure if that would work; personally, I'd use filter_complex, as above:

```
ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv -i /tmp/icon.png \
-filter_complex '[0:v]scale=480:-1[int];[int][1]overlay=W/2-w/2:H/2-h/2[outv]' \
-map [outv] -map 0:a -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -c:v libvpx -b:v 384k output.webm
```

Comment: if i wanna first scale and then add water mark what must i do? `[in][watermark] scale=480:-1,overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2[out]` did not work.

Comment: can you aid me to solve it ?

Comment: @sweb I've appended instructions on how to do that onto the answer

Comment: ty again for great aid man.